# Offset when convert SVG to font with Glyphter.com - Offset

Tags: glyphicons, fontello, svg-font

I created a simple SVG in Adobe Illustrator and then I save it as a SVG:

[image]

I then upload this SVG to glyphter.com and it looks perfectly centered:

[image]

I then drop the .svg file generated by the Glyphter download into fontello and I use it in my website but all the ones I generate are offset like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why the offset is there? Shouldn't it be cenetered?

I even tried making my SVG graphic save with artboards and i used artboards of height and width the same so its a square.

Comment: Do you have to use **Glyphter** & **Fontello** exclusively?  I can give you a great answer on how to fix the issue pronto, but with FontForge.

Comment: Thanks @argon - I only have access to free open source tools :( I would gladly accept your answer though as I would learn from it and try to use FontForge as I am stuck on this :(

Comment: No sweat, it's free and open-source. I've posted an answer as discussed. If you need more info I'll gladly update the answer with more specific instructions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use **FontForge** for low-level control of the glyphs in almost any font.

- FontForge is free: https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/
- It can be installed on *Windows, Mac OS X and GNU+Linux*
- You can manipulate individual glyphs, and perform bulk operations
- When you're done editing your font, you can export it to almost any font-mime-type (ttf, otf, woff, svg, *etc*)

This is a good manual for installing and using FontForge:
http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/index.html

The information you will probably need for this specific issue is here:
http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Spacing_Metrics_and_Kerning.html

**Bulk centering all glyphs:**

- open the font you want to edit
- to see all the relevant glyphs select *Encoding -> Compact* from the top menu
- to select all the glyphs, press `Ctrl+A` on your keyboard, then
- to center all the glyphs relatively, select *Metrics -> Center in Width* from the top-menu.

The following screen-shots illustrate the last 3 points in sequence - mentioned above:

[image]

[image]

When you're done, select *File -> Generate Fonts* from the top-menu and choose the font-type you want, choose the target folder, and hit *Save*.

Comment: Wow thanks very much this is actually pretty darn good! Will try it out! :)

Comment: Pleasure :D - I've just updated the answer - with instructions & screenshots to do exactly what you need done ;)

Comment: Oh wow! A sincere thank you, those screenshots are immensely helpful!